# Crashlytics Not working properly in El Capitan ver 10.11.1

Tags: ios9, xcode7, crashlytics, osx-elcapitan

El Capitan ver 10.11.1 (15B22c)

Xcode Version 7.0 (7A220)

I was integrating Crashlytics to new ios project. Now after adding new app to Crashlytics, next step is to add code to run script to project target and build your project, build was successful and proceeded to next step that is importing Crashlytics Framework to project by dragging and dropping suitcase icon on fabric.app to project. Framework got imported but fabric.app does not detects that it was imported and also does not show next step (stuck here).

Thanks You For every help you can provide in any way.

Update (23/11/2015) : Working Porperly OSX Version 10.11 (15A284), XCode Version 7.1 (7B91b), CrashAnalytics Version 2.0.5 (1062)

---------------------Closed-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: There’s not enough information here for anybody to be able to provide you with any real help.

Comment: Isn't the next step to run the script that submits the symbols when the build has completed?

Comment: I am running XCode 7 and Crashlytics 3.4. Created a build and added a test crash. I never received the crash report. Everything seems to be OK. Also DSYMs are there.

Comment: Update : Working Porperly OSX Version  10.11 (15A284), XCode Version 7.1 (7B91b), CrashAnalytics Version  2.0.5 (1062)